# Magento 2, PageBuilder - adding custom content type

Tags: module, magento2

I'm trying to add custom content type to existing page builder module in Magento 2 following https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/create-custom-content-type/overview.html

Bit of a problem that docs is kind of outdated, but the biggest issue for me right now, is that for some reason, panel with settings of content type is not loading. Console doesn't throw any errors and I'm not even sure how to debug this.

Normal behavior: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OClPda-WGuc7idNogUnTz0wi4ZSk_Qu_

Behavior of custom content type (settings are not loading at all): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I-IeTImec-M8DuLfgjiA193mhm0Fwtd8

Maybe someone already stumbled upon issue like this and know possible ways to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found out what problem was, so I'm answering this question in case someone will need this in future.

Check your ui_component xml structure, I was having an issue with naming there (namespace was not correct), and that's why it was not loading.